# Scrapyd: How to set scrapyd task priority?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I have several scrapy projects. I deploy all of them with scrapyd. Some of the spiders are slow while others are fast. Now, I want to run fast spiders first. How to do?

Comment: This is very general question, you may get some answers if you publish the attempts you have made to solve your problem. Have you tried to write your own code?

Comment: has it worked for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. But I read the source code of `scrapyd` and it seems that scrapyd can handle it. This is not documented, however.

You need to add an argument named `priority` with the desired value. The default priority is 0.

For instance:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d priority=1
```